# Make table only full width - inline css?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to make my table go full width (prior to my table my content is restricted next to three blocks which I'm cool with).

The table appears after the words "A selection of awards won:"

You can see the page - [here](https://www.workbooks.com/test-about-page)

Would this be possible with inline css?

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is removing your table from the:

```
<div id="right">
```

And creating a new div bottom or something with 100% width under the div right/ div left.

```
<div id="bottom" style="width: 100%"><table>
```

This should fix your problem,

Comment: Thanks, how do I align it to the left? I tried: <div align="left" id="bottom" style="width: 1000px"> but no luck

Comment: Still no luck, I think the block might be affecting things. Currently looks like: <div align="left" id="bottom" style="width: 1000px" text-align: left;>

Comment: text-align left is css code so you  have to put it in your tag like this: style="text-align: left"

Comment: Thanks - I used "<div align="left" id="bottom" style="width: 1000px" style="text-align: left">" but again no luck :/

Comment: You still did not remove the table from the div right you have to create a new div bottom and put the table in that.

Comment: if you really want to use it like this add this code: style="margin-left -220px;" but i don't recomment this.

Comment: Thanks, how do I remove the table from div right? I never used this code when putting the table in?

Comment: Its just simply copying and pasting it into a new div with 100% width under the left/right divs.

Comment: Please confirm the line I need to put in.

Answer (score -1):

You can't go full width because your container `.sub-content` is not full width...

If you want to go full width you will have to put your table in another container that is at the same level as the `.left` and `.right` container but with full width.

Something like :

```
<div id="content-sub">
  <div id="left">...</div>
  <div id="right">...</div>
  <div id="bottom">
    <!-- Your table goes here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

with :

```
#bottom{
  display: block;
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply copy your your table code out and place it **just above** this code

```
<br clear="all" />

<div id="footers">
```